# Haskell Type vs Data Constructor

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell from [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com). I am having trouble understanding type constructors and data constructors. For example, I don't really understand the difference between this:

```
data Car = Car { company :: String  
               , model :: String  
               , year :: Int  
               } deriving (Show)
```

and this:

```
data Car a b c = Car { company :: a  
                     , model :: b  
                     , year :: c   
                     } deriving (Show)
```

I understand that the first is simply using one constructor (`Car`) to built data of type `Car`. I don't really understand the second one.

Also, how do data types defined like this:

```
data Color = Blue | Green | Red
```

fit into all of this?

From what I understand, the third example (`Color`) is a type which can be in three states: `Blue`, `Green` or `Red`. But that conflicts with how I understand the first two examples: is it that the type `Car` can only be in one state, `Car`, which can take various parameters to build? If so, how does the second example fit in?

Essentially, I am looking for an explanation that unifies the above three code examples/constructs.

Comment: Your Car example may be a little confusing because `Car` is both a type constructor (on the left side of the `=`) and a data constructor (on the right side). In the first example, the `Car` type constructor takes no arguments, in the second example it takes three. In both examples, the `Car` data constructor takes three arguments (but the types of those arguments are in one case fixed and in the other parameterised).

Comment: the first is simply using one data constructor (`Car :: String -> String -> Int -> Car`) to build data of type `Car`. the second is simply using one data constructor (`Car :: a -> b -> c -> Car a b c`) to build data of type `Car a b c`.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

In a `data` declaration, a *type constructor* is the thing on the left hand side of the equals sign. The *data constructor(s)* are the things on the right hand side of the equals sign. You use type constructors where a type is expected, and you use data constructors where a value is expected.

### Data constructors

To make things simple, we can start with an example of a type that represents a colour.

```
data Colour = Red | Green | Blue
```

Here, we have three data constructors. `Colour` is a type, and `Green` is a constructor that contains a value of type `Colour`. Similarly, `Red` and `Blue` are both constructors that construct values of type `Colour`. We could imagine spicing it up though!

```
data Colour = RGB Int Int Int
```

We still have just the type `Colour`, but `RGB` is not a value – it's a function taking three Ints and *returning* a value! `RGB` has the type

```
RGB :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Colour
```

`RGB` is a data constructor that is a function taking some *values* as its arguments, and then uses those to construct a new value. If you have done any object-oriented programming, you should recognise this. In OOP, constructors also take some values as arguments and return a new value!

In this case, if we apply `RGB` to three values, we get a colour value!

```
Prelude> RGB 12 92 27
#0c5c1b
```

We have *constructed a value* of type `Colour` by applying the data constructor. A data constructor either contains a value like a variable would, or takes other values as its argument and creates a new *value*. If you have done previous programming, this concept shouldn't be very strange to you.

### Intermission

If you'd want to construct a binary tree to store `String`s, you could imagine doing something like

```
data SBTree = Leaf String
            | Branch String SBTree SBTree
```

What we see here is a type `SBTree` that contains two data constructors. In other words, there are two functions (namely `Leaf` and `Branch`) that will construct values of the `SBTree` type. If you're not familiar with how binary trees work, just hang in there. You don't actually need to know how binary trees work, only that this one stores `String`s in some way.

We also see that both data constructors take a `String` argument – this is the String they are going to store in the tree.

But! What if we also wanted to be able to store `Bool`, we'd have to create a new binary tree. It could look something like this:

```
data BBTree = Leaf Bool
            | Branch Bool BBTree BBTree
```

### Type constructors

Both `SBTree` and `BBTree` are type constructors. But there's a glaring problem. Do you see how similar they are? That's a sign that you really want a parameter somewhere.

So we can do this:

```
data BTree a = Leaf a
             | Branch a (BTree a) (BTree a)
```

Now we introduce a *type variable* `a` as a parameter to the type constructor. In this declaration, `BTree` has become a function. It takes a *type* as its argument and it returns a new *type*.

> It is important here to consider the difference between a *concrete type* (examples include `Int`, `[Char]` and `Maybe Bool`) which is a type that can be assigned to a value in your program, and a *type constructor function* which you need to feed a type to be able to be assigned to a value. A value can never be of type "list", because it needs to be a "list *of something*". In the same spirit, a value can never be of type "binary tree", because it needs to be a "binary tree storing *something*".

If we pass in, say, `Bool` as an argument to `BTree`, it returns the type `BTree Bool`, which is a binary tree that stores `Bool`s. Replace every occurrence of the type variable `a` with the type `Bool`, and you can see for yourself how it's true.

If you want to, you can view `BTree` as a function with the *kind*

```
BTree :: * -> *
```

Kinds are somewhat like types – the `*` indicates a concrete type, so we say `BTree` is from a concrete type to a concrete type.

### Wrapping up

Step back here a moment and take note of the similarities.

- A *data constructor* is a "function" that takes 0 or more *values* and gives you back a new value.
- A *type constructor* is a "function" that takes 0 or more *types* and gives you back a new type.

Data constructors with parameters are cool if we want slight variations in our values – we put those variations in parameters and let the guy who creates the value decide what arguments they are going to put in. In the same sense, type constructors with parameters are cool if we want slight variations in our types! We put those variations as parameters and let the guy who creates the type decide what arguments they are going to put in.

### A case study

As the home stretch here, we can consider the `Maybe a` type. Its definition is

```
data Maybe a = Nothing
             | Just a
```

Here, `Maybe` is a type constructor that returns a concrete type. `Just` is a data constructor that returns a value. `Nothing` is a data constructor that contains a value. If we look at the type of `Just`, we see that

```
Just :: a -> Maybe a
```

In other words, `Just` takes a value of type `a` and returns a value of type `Maybe a`. If we look at the kind of `Maybe`, we see that

```
Maybe :: * -> *
```

In other words, `Maybe` takes a concrete type and returns a concrete type.

Once again! The difference between a concrete type and a type constructor function. You cannot create a list of `Maybe`s - if you try to execute

```
[] :: [Maybe]
```

you'll get an error. You can however create a list of `Maybe Int`, or `Maybe a`. That's because `Maybe` is a type constructor function, but a list needs to contain values of a concrete type. `Maybe Int` and `Maybe a` are concrete types (or if you want, calls to type constructor functions that return concrete types.)

Comment: I always thought that they are also called "(data|type) constructors" when the have no parameters. Can someone confirm this distinction?

Comment: At least GHCi calls them that: 

let f = Blah //
Not in scope: data constructor `Blah' //
let f = undefined :: Blah //
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Blah'

Comment: In your first example, both RED GREEN and BLUE are constructors that take no arguments.

Comment: @MikeHartl: They are indeed called data/type constructors, even if they have no parameters. Hence, a data constructor *can* be a function (if it takes arguments), but it doesn't need to be one.

Comment: The claim that in `data Colour = Red | Green | Blue` "we don't have any constructors at all" is plain wrong. Type constructors and data constructors don't need to take arguments, see e.g. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constructor which points out that in `data Tree a = Tip | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)`, "there are two data constructors, Tip and Node".

Comment: I have taken note of your corrections, and I will try to reword this post as soon as I get home. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can Maybe's type be `Maybe :: a -> Maybe a`? Since `Maybe a` is still a type constructor, does that mean it's impossible to write in the data-context, `let something = Maybe(Int)`? Because that would make the data ambiguous? And when you say "where a type is expected", that means in stuff like type signatures, declarations, data/newtype/type.. etc. But not in the actual "code", such as variable assignment, function application.. etc.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai With the right GHC extensions, that would probably work. But in vanilla Haskell, types are not expected in variable assignments, function application and so on. Types are only expected in type signatures, type declarations and such. Was that an answer to your question?

Comment: Yea pretty much. But I did some reading about Kinds, and so now my perspective is that the word "kind" is like asking what the type of type is it? Whereas "type" is like asking what the type of this value is it? Which is why I can't type `:t Maybe` but I can do `:kind! Maybe`. I wonder if there is some language joins the concepts of types and values together, so that all constructors are just at some level of abstraction.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You are absolutely correct! Kinds are the "types of types." A common approach to joining the concepts of types and values is called *dependent typing*. [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org/) is a Haskell-inspired dependently typed language. With the right GHC extensions, you can also get somewhat close to dependent typing in Haskell. (Some people have been joking that "Haskell research is about figuring out how close to dependent types we can get without having dependent types.")

Comment: There's also Omega which has an infinite type hierarchy.

Comment: Can you also explain what it means to simply have `data Z`? As in a data declaration without a data constructor. So now you have just a type constructor called Z, but with no way of constructing data that facilitates Z?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai It's actually not possible to have an empty data declaration in standard Haskell. But there is a GHC extension (`-XEmptyDataDecls`) that lets you do that. Since, as you say, there are no values with that type, a function `f :: Int -> Z` may for example never return (because what would it return?) They can however be useful for [when you want types but don't really care about values](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type).

Comment: Really it's not possible? I just tried in GHC, and it ran it without error. I didn't have to load any GHC extensions, just vanilla GHC. I could then write `:k Z` and it just gave me a star.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Apparently empty data declarations are allowed in Haskell 2010, but not Haskell 98. My bad. (You can verify by running GHC with `-XHaskell98` and then trying the same thing.)

Comment: Wow. Thank you - I'm in the middle of a Haskell talk and your explanation is concise and clear enough to be a supplementary resource *while listening to a talk*

Comment: What's up with the Hex Code suddenly popping up in your example? Prelude> RGB 12 92 27
#0c5c1b.     Is that just for illustrating purposes?

Comment: @Nimi Yeah, that's just a custom Show instance I wrote to make it clear that I've actually created a new type of value, and I'm not just getting GHCi to print whatever I typed. Now, two years later, I'm still not sure that was a good idea but I've let it stay.

Comment: _`Nothing` is a data constructor that contains a value._ Wouldn't it be more accurate to say "`Nothing` is a data constructor that itself represents a single value whose concrete type is inferred eventually depending on the context"? That is to say `Nothing` can represent exactly one value, but this value can be of different type. This is probably nit-picking - I'm just learning.

Comment: @ftor: not sure what you are saying. In the Prelude, Nothing is of type Maybe and Maybe only.

Comment: Hm, I thought `Nothing` is of type `Maybe a`, i.e. depending on the context it is inferred as `Maybe String`, `Maybe Integer` etc. So `Nothing` is a polymorphic value although it acts like a constant. A constant usually contains a value, but `Nothing` doesn't. It is a value constructor that never constructs a value. What remains is the constructor itself, against which one can pattern match.

Comment: @ftor I see what you are saying, sorry! That's a really good observation that probably warrants its own SO question. I understand it this way: There are two levels of "determine concrete type based on context". One level – type classes – determine concrete type based on run-time context. The other level – type inference – which is the one involved in the `Nothing :: Maybe a` case, uses information known statically. The compiler picks a type for `a` depending on context, but this type is merely a compile time annotation of sorts. It still uses the same `Nothing` for all cases. So yes and no? :D

Comment: Thought you said data constructor is on the right side, why `BTree` is on the right side, yet it is type constructor?

Comment: Isn't it the type of a value given to a data constructor instead of a type constructor (since it appears on the RHS) ?

Answer (score 52):

Haskell has *algebraic data types*, which very few other languages have. This is perhaps what's confusing you.

In other languages, you can usually make a "record", "struct" or similar, which has a bunch of named fields that hold various different types of data. You can also sometimes make an "enumeration", which has a (small) set of fixed possible values (e.g., your `Red`, `Green` and `Blue`).

In Haskell, you can *combine* both of these at the same time. Weird, but true!

Why is it called "algebraic"? Well, the nerds talk about "sum types" and "product types". For example:

```
data Eg1 = One Int | Two String
```

An `Eg1` value is basically *either* an integer or a string. So the set of all possible `Eg1` values is the "sum" of the set of all possible integer values and all possible string values. Thus, nerds refer to `Eg1` as a "sum type". On the other hand:

```
data Eg2 = Pair Int String
```

Every `Eg2` value consists of *both* an integer and a string. So the set of all possible `Eg2` values is the Cartesian product of the set of all integers and the set of all strings. The two sets are "multiplied" together, so this is a "product type".

Haskell's algebraic types are *sum types of product types*. You give a constructor multiple fields to make a product type, and you have multiple constructors to make a sum (of products).

As an example of why that might be useful, suppose you have something that outputs data as either XML or JSON, and it takes a configuration record - but obviously, the configuration settings for XML and for JSON are totally different. So you *might* do something like this:

```
data Config = XML_Config {...} | JSON_Config {...}
```

(With some suitable fields in there, obviously.) You can't do stuff like this in normal programming languages, which is why most people aren't used to it.

Comment: great! just one thing, "They can ... be constructed in nearly any language", [says Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). :) In e.g. C/++, that's `union`s, with a tag discipline. :)

Comment: Yeah, but every time I mention `union`, people look at me like "who the hell ever uses _that_??" ;-)

Comment: I have seen a lot of `union` used in my C career. Please don't make it sound unnecessary because that is not the case.

Answer (score 32):

Start with the simplest case:

```
data Color = Blue | Green | Red
```

This defines a "type constructor" `Color` which takes no arguments - and it has three "data constructors", `Blue`, `Green` and `Red`. None of the data constructors takes any arguments. This means that there are three of type `Color`: `Blue`, `Green` and `Red`.

A data constructor is used when you need to create a value of some sort. Like:

```
myFavoriteColor :: Color
myFavoriteColor = Green
```

creates a value `myFavoriteColor` using the `Green` data constructor - and `myFavoriteColor` will be of type `Color` since that's the type of values produced by the data constructor.

A type constructor is used when you need to create a *type* of some sort. This is usually the case when writing signatures:

```
isFavoriteColor :: Color -> Bool
```

In this case, you are calling the `Color` type constructor (which takes no arguments).

Still with me?

Now, imagine you not only wanted to create red/green/blue values but you also wanted to specify an "intensity". Like, a value between 0 and 256. You could do that by adding an argument to each of the data constructors, so you end up with:

```
data Color = Blue Int | Green Int | Red Int
```

Now, each of the three data constructors takes an argument of type `Int`. The type constructor (`Color`) still doesn't take any arguments. So, my favorite color being a darkish green, I could write

```
    myFavoriteColor :: Color
    myFavoriteColor = Green 50
```

And again, it calls the `Green` data constructor and I get a value of type `Color`.

Imagine if you don't want to dictate how people express the intensity of a color. Some might want a numeric value like we just did. Others may be fine with just a boolean indicating "bright" or "not so bright". The solution to this is to not hardcode `Int` in the data constructors but rather use a type variable:

```
data Color a = Blue a | Green a | Red a
```

Now, our type constructor takes one argument (another type which we just call `a`!) and all of the data constructors will take one argument (a value!) of that type `a`. So you could have

```
myFavoriteColor :: Color Bool
myFavoriteColor = Green False
```

or

```
myFavoriteColor :: Color Int
myFavoriteColor = Green 50
```

Notice how we call the `Color` type constructor with an argument (another type) to get the "effective" type which will be returned by the data constructors. This touches the concept of [kinds](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Kind) which you may want to read about over a cup of coffee or two.

Now we figured out what data constructors and type constructors are, and how data constructors can take other values as arguments and type constructors can take other types as arguments. HTH.

Comment: @kqr: A data constructor can be nullary, but then it's not a function anymore. A function is something which takes an argument and yields a value, i.e something with `->` in the signature.

Comment: Can a value point to multiple types? Or is every value associated with only 1 type and that's it?

Comment: This is by far the most useful answer to me as a haskell layman. So one can think of type constructors in a similar way like about generics in C# or Java?

Comment: @jrg There is some overlap, but it's not specifically because of type constructors but because of type variables, e.g. the `a` in `data Color a = Red a`. `a` is a placeholder for an arbitrary type. You can have the same in plain functions though, e.g. a function of type `(a, b) -> a` takes a tuple of two values (of types `a` and `b`) and yields the first value. It's a "generic" function in that it doesn't dictate the type of the tuple elements - it only specifies that the function yields a value of the same type as the first tuple element.

Comment: +1 `Now, our type constructor takes one argument (another type which we just call a!) and all of the data constructors will take one argument (a value!) of that type a.` This is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

As others pointed out, polymorphism isn't that terrible useful here. Let's look at another example you're probably already familiar with:

```
Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

This type has two data constructors. `Nothing` is somewhat boring, it doesn't contain any useful data. On the other hand `Just` contains a value of `a` - whatever type `a` may have. Let's write a function which uses this type, e.g. getting the head of an `Int` list, if there is any (I hope you agree this is more useful than throwing an error):

```
maybeHead :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
maybeHead [] = Nothing
maybeHead (x:_) = Just x

> maybeHead [1,2,3]    -- Just 1
> maybeHead []         -- None
```

So in this case `a` is an `Int`, but it would work as well for any other type. In fact you can make our function work for every type of list (even without changing the implementation):

```
maybeHead :: [t] -> Maybe t
maybeHead [] = Nothing
maybeHead (x:_) = Just x
```

On the other hand you can write functions which accept only a certain type of `Maybe`, e.g.

```
doubleMaybe :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
doubleMaybe Just x = Just (2*x)
doubleMaybe Nothing= Nothing
```

So long story short, with polymorphism you give your own type the flexibility to work with values of different other types.

In your example, you may decide at some point that `String` isn't sufficient to identify the company, but it needs to have its own type `Company` (which holds additional data like country, address, back accounts etc). Your first implementation of `Car` would need to change to use `Company` instead of `String` for its first value. Your second implementation is just fine, you use it as `Car Company String Int` and it would work as before (of course functions accessing company data need to be changed).

Comment: Can you use type constructors in the data-context of another data declaration? Something like `data Color = Blue ; data Bright = Color`? I tried it in ghci, and it seems that the Color in the type constructor has nothing to do with the Color data constructor in the Bright definition. There are just 2 Color constructors, one which is Data and the other is Type.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I don't think that you can do this, and I'm not even sure what you want to achieve with this. You can "wrap" an existing type using `data` or `newtype` (e.g. `data Bright = Bright Color`), or you can use `type` in order to define a synonym (e.g. `type Bright = Color`).

Comment: Hallo Landei. Hier Stadtspatz. As a Haskell beginner, I "get" this -- kind of -- but only because I slogged through "The Little MLer" which goes straight into this bizarre world of using types, type constructors as a sort of recursive, "out of body" sugared lambda calculus programming. This stuff just isn't easy, and it's not very well explained anywhere, i.e., this sudden use of invented types as the actual expressions. If all else fails, people, take a break and try "The Little MLer." Even though ML is a different language, it's virtually the same as Haskell type system-wise.

Answer (score 5):

The second one has the notion of "polymorphism" in it.

The `a b c` can be of any type. For example, `a` can be a `[String]`, `b` can be `[Int]`
and `c` can be `[Char]`.

While the first one's type is fixed: company is a `String`, model is a `String` and year is `Int`.

The Car example might not show the significance of using polymorphism. But imagine your data is of the list type. A list can contain `String, Char, Int ...` In those situations, you will need the second way of defining your data.

As to the third way I don't think it needs to fit into the previous type. It's just one other way of defining data in Haskell.

This is my humble opinion as a beginner myself.

Btw: Make sure that you train your brain well and feel comfortable to this. It is the key to understand Monad later.

Answer (score 2):

It's about *types*: In the first case, your set the types `String` (for company and model) and `Int` for year. In the second case, your are more generic. `a`, `b`, and `c` may be the very same types as in the first example, **or** something completely different. E.g., it may be useful to give the year as string instead of integer. And if you want, you may even use your `Color` type.