# Accessing values in haskell custom data type

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to haskell and need to use a specific data type for a problem I am working on.

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node [Tree a]
deriving (Show, Eq)
```

So when I make an instance of this e.g Node[Leaf 1, Leaf2, Leaf 3] how do I access these? It won't let me use head or tail or indexing with !! .

Comment: A note on terminology.  What you have defined is a "type constuctor" (`Tree`) which can be provided with a type argument to produce a type (ex `Tree Int`) and a couple "data constructors" (`Leaf` and `Node`) which can be provided value argument to produce a value (not an "instance").  See, for example, [this prior question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204308/haskell-type-vs-data-constructor).

Comment: That's good, since partial functions as `head,tail,!!` should be avoided as much as possible, using pattern matching instead.

Answer (score 4):

You perform **pattern matching**. For example if you want the first child, you can use:

```
firstChild :: Tree a -> Maybe (Tree a)
firstChild (Node (h:_)) = Just h
firstChild _ = Nothing
```

Here we wrap the answer in a `Maybe` type, since it is possible that we process a `Leaf x` or a `Node []`, such that there is no first child.

Or we can for instance obtain the *i*-th item with:

```
iThChild :: Int -> Tree a -> Tree a
iThChild i (Node cs) = cs !! i
```

So here we unwrap the `Node` constructor, obtain the list of children `cs`, and then perform `cs !! i` to obtain the *i*-th child. Note however that `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a` is usually a bit of an anti-pattern: it is unsafe, since we have no guarantees that the list contains enough elements, and using `length` is an anti-pattern as well, since the list can have infinite length, so we can no do such bound check.

Usually if one writes algorithms in Haskell, one tends to make use of *linear* access, and write *total* functions: functions that always return something.

Comment: What do you mean, linear access?